# How to use left join in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the below query which is fetching the correct results in mysql when i write the same query in grails it is throwing an error "Path expected for join"

```
select u.username,u.transactioncode,count(distinct t.rolename) roles
from user u 
left join transaction t on u.transactioncode=t.transactioncode 
group by u.username, u.transactioncode; 

How to change the query?

Modifying the query to make it work in grails

function(int id)
 {
   def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        def output = sql.rows("select 
        u.username,u.transactioncode,count(distinct t.rolename) roles from 
        user u left join transaction t on 
        u.transactioncode=t.transactioncode where u.userid=:id group by 
        u.username, u.transactioncode")
       sql.close();
 }

 It throws an error in the where condition You have an error in your SQL 
 syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
 the right syntax to use near ':id.
```

Comment: How are you implementing this query in grails?
Can you use criterias?

Comment: Below is my query in grails:                 
username.executeQuery("select u.username,u.transactioncode,count(distinct t.rolename) roles
from user u 
left join transaction t on u.transactioncode=t.transactioncode 
group by u.username, u.transactioncode");

Comment: This is now a HQL query. Does  User have a transaction declaration inside the domain class. If so the query should be `select new map (u.username as username ,u.transactioncode as transaction code,count(distinct t.rolename) as roles) from user u left join u.transaction t group by u.username, u.transactioncode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to use [Groovy SQL](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html). For this to work, you should inject `dataSource` into your service or controller:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource

DataSource dataSource
```

and then execute the query like

```
new Sql(dataSource).rows(q)
```

Where `q` would be your exact query.

[Here](https://dzone.com/articles/grails-goodness-using-groovy) is a good tutorial for using Groovy SQL with Grails.

---

I don't even know if it's possible to use left joins in inline HQL - and that's what should be used with `executeQuery`. `Criterias`, as mentioned by @JMa, would be a valid option, but they - I think - are generally used to query domain objects and you need custom results set. [This](http://tatiyants.com/how-and-when-to-use-various-gorm-querying-options/) is another good explanation for when to use different kinds of querying options in Grails.

Comment: Hi suricatta thank you for the solution and providing the links about the queries.

Comment: I am glad that I could help, GrailsLearner. And the links are really good, at the beginning it's easy to get lost when it comes to queries.

Comment: Hi suricatta i modified the  above query to make it work in grails.But when i use where condition in the above format it throws the above error.How exactly weshould use the where condition in SQL.